# The data is not getting populated in the textview-Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am a beginner in android app dev. As a start, I tried to develop a small app with the below code. There are no compile time or runtime errors. But it is not taking in my input nor am i getting the output populated.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.RadioButton;  
import android.widget.TextView;
/*import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;*/

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    //private EditText text;  
    RadioButton mileButton,kmhButton ;
    TextView textview1,textview2;
    Button calcButton;
    private View.OnClickListener droidTapListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("HIIIIIIIIII");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
        return true;
    }

    public void calculate() {  

   mileButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);  //radiobutton objects
         kmhButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);  

         calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     //button obj
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(droidTapListener);   //setting up click listeners.

        TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        /*if(text.getText().length()==0)
            System.out.println("Empty Value");*/

        if(textview1.getText().length()==0)
            System.out.println("Enter a valid input.");

        /*Toast.makeText(this, "enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  
        .show(); */

        double inputValue = Double.parseDouble(textview1.getText().toString()); 
        if (mileButton.isChecked()) {  
            //text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToMiles(inputValue))); 
            double res= convertToMiles(inputValue);
            String finalresult = new Double(res).toString();
            textview2.setText(finalresult);

            System.out.println("RESULT"+finalresult);

            // uncheck "to miles" Button  
            mileButton.setChecked(false);  
            // check "to km/h" Button  
            kmhButton.setChecked(true);  
        } else { /* if kmhButton isChecked() */  
            //text.setText(String.valueOf(convertToKmh(inputValue))); 
            double res= convertToKmh(inputValue);
            String finalresult = new Double(res).toString();
            textview2.setText(finalresult);

            System.out.println("RESULT"+finalresult);

            // uncheck "to km/h" Button  
            kmhButton.setChecked(false);  
            // check "to miles" Button  
            mileButton.setChecked(true);  

        }  
    } 



private double convertToMiles(double inputValue) {  
    // convert km/h to miles 
    double res=inputValue * 1.609344;
    return res;

   //return (inputValue * 1.609344);  
}  

private double convertToKmh(double inputValue) {  
    // convert miles to km/h  
    return (inputValue * 0.621372);  
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    calculate();
}
}
```

Comment: You did't call your calculate() in onCreate() ...and also use Toast instead of println..and use a button to set onClickListener..so on button click you can call the calculate method and check the text id fill or null :)

Comment: First call this `calculate()`  on `onCreate()` method and also change this `String finalresult = String.valueOf(res);`

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding a few core concepts of Android programming. Why not trying to learn the basics by reading a book (Professional Android 4 Application Development by Reto Meier is pertty good) or online courses like https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853 ?

Comment: Thanks Guys! but while trying to call calculate() on onCreate(), My app is getting aborted.

Answer (score 0):

You have set you onclickListener inside calculate method. means Unless your calculate method dont get called the onClickListener will not invoke, and if onClickListener will not get registered calculate() methode will not get called.

Do this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("HIIIIIIIIII");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

     calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    calcButton.setOnClickListener(droidTapListener);  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should init your view component in onCreate(), so move this piece of code in on create and remove TypeDefinition before text view you already has declared this variable.

```
   mileButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);  //radiobutton objects
   kmhButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);  

   calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     //button obj
   calcButton.setOnClickListener(this);   //you droidTapListener isn't initialize and you implements clickListener so use this for listening this event.
   textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Do not forget to add @override for your onClick() function so your tap on the button will run the onclick function so the calculate function.

Comment: initializing the objects on onCreat(), don't they become local to that func alone? using these objects within calculate() gives me error:\

Comment: You have declare your activity variables
`RadioButton mileButton,kmhButton ;
TextView textview1,textview2;
Button calcButton;` so you can use it everywhere in your activity (onCreate(), calculate() etc.) 

The main point is about your listener for your calcButton use this and override the onClick method